# What was the purpose to animal sacrifices?

Tags: sin, forgiveness, sacrifice

I've never completely understood the purpose as to why God required that the Israelite's should kill an animal in order for God to forgive them.

Comment: Maybe this should belong to judaism.se ?

Comment: Answer to this I guess would be same as [this question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/16047/why-did-god-make-garments-of-skin-for-adam-and-eve-when-they-had-already-made-cl/16051#16051)

Answer (score 5):

There were two main meanings to this.  The first was as a symbol of Christ, whose blood makes it possible for everyone to have their sins forgiven.  The second is as a sacrifice in the more traditional sense: willingly giving up something important and valuable.  And when your animals are both your livelihood and the food on your family's table, giving the best of your flocks to the Lord (and the sacrifices were required to be the best, not just any old animal) is quite a sacrifice indeed!  By the Law of Sacrifice, the Lord teaches us to have faith and trust in him instead of getting too attached to material possessions and trusting in them to bring us happiness and success in life.

Comment: Indeed, that it was required to be "first-fruits", and the very best without spot or blemish, directly correlates to be a type of Christ.

Comment: However, not all Israelites were shepherds, having neither flock nor herd. Accordingly, such an Israelite could simply purchase an animal from those who sold them for such a purpose. Ergo, his only loss would be monetary (which yeah, that still hurts the pocket book).

Answer (score -1):

Genesis 2: 15-24 and Genesis 3: 1-24 tells the story of our beginning;  And simply stated: The woman snared by the dazzling of jewels which was Satan's appearance and her child like-mind could not properly understand, the words she heard;  She taking it to her husband and by his own desire accepted the words of the fallen immortal son, Satan, he created to be a cunning persuader, a deceiver, and destroyer, for his work on the earth is to destroy all men who will not hear the truth in God's word.  For their fate will be as his in the latter days to come.  But the disobedience of having too much knowledge at one time is and remain harmful to us.  Therefore innocent animals were killed by God to provide clothing and heat for our unprotected bodies.  For in sin there is shame and eternal death; this, we their children have been trying to cover up our inborn shame, in the sight of God the only Living Son of the Father, in the day of our creation.

Comment: Sin the transgression, breaking the law of God brings in reality that something must die; There was no other man on earth at that time and therefore temporarily God substituted animals to die for man; but it was ineffectual, as they did not break His commandment, but the man.  And the death of Jesus Christ ended the practice of animal sacrifice and instituted salvation under His blood by which man can be redeemed; and yes to give up what you have is costly and it hurts; but what is more important to leave sin and to live forever?

Comment: Welcome to the site. In the future, you can add content to your post by clicking [edit] below the post. Comments are intended to be a place for people to help improve answers, so they are eventually deleted.